# Objc class doesn't recognize Swift class

Tags: objective-c, swift, objc-bridging-header

I could not import swift class inside my objective c project following these steps:

Enviroment:

Xcode: 10.0

Swift: 4.2

1 - Ctrl+N to generate a new swift file

2 - Selected “Create Bridging Header” from xcode question

3 - On Target -> build settings, search for "Packaging" and turn on "Defines Module"

4 - Imported #import "MyProjectModuleName-Swift.h" in my objc .m file

5 - Trying to call my swift method and nothing seems to work, i'm not capable to call it because my .m class doesn't recognize my .swift file.

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to use an swift class inside an objective c project and spent a lot of time trying to make it works with no success.

All answer didn't work for me until i got the right path for my Project-Swift.h.

That was the trick that saved my life.

---

Follow this steps and you will success!

1 - Create your xcode project

2 - Create a new .swift file

3 - A dialogue box will appear, make sure to select “Create Bridging Header” when prompted.

4 - On Target -> build settings, search for "Packaging" and turn on "Defines Module"

5 - On your swift file (sample)

```
import Foundation

@objcMembers

class MyClass: NSObject {
    public func test () -> String {
        return "Swift says hi to objc class!"
    }
}
```

Here pay attention to **@objcMembers** that will let objc class recognize swift class!

[Find it here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-the-objcmembers-attribute)

6 - On your objc class .m or .h file import your auto generated Project-Swift.h file on step 3

My goal was to import it:

```
#import <Teste-Swift.h>
```

And not:

```
#import "Teste-Swift.h"
```

Thats it, after a headache i got tha answer

So at the end, my .m file was like this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <Teste-Swift.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //-------------        
    MySwiftClass *myswiftclass = [[MySwiftClass alloc] init];
    NSString *string = [myswiftclass test];
    NSLog(@"%@",string);
}


@end
```

An my .swift file:

```
import Foundation

@objcMembers

class MySwiftClass: NSObject {
    public func test () -> String {
        return "Swift says hi second swift class!"
    }
}
```

I hope this can help you folks.